# HTTPS->HTTP via Fiddler

Tags: https, fiddler

I'm looking for a way to use Fiddler to proxy an HTTPS session into an HTTP session, so the explorer will use an HTTP session while the Fiddler handles the HTTPS session in front of the server:

Client (explorer) <--http--> Fiddler <--https--> Server

Can anyone say if this can be done via Fiddler scripting?

If you have another idea how to do this with another tool (not Fiddler), I'm open to suggestions :)

Thanks!
Yohay

Answer (score 19):

@troy's answer is nice but not enough. You should handle CONNECT's:

```
    if (oSession.HostnameIs("app.yourdomain.com") ) 
     {  
        // Handle CONNECT Tunnels
        if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT"))
        {
            oSession["x-replywithtunnel"] = "FakeTunnel";
            return;
        }           

        oSession.fullUrl = "http://somedomain:someport" + oSession.PathAndQuery;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day!

Comment: Where to put it?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
if (oSession.fullUrl.StartsWith("http://"))
{
  oSession.oRequest.headers.UriScheme = "https";
}
```

Comment: where should i put this, is there a link or reference how to this?